# NetSuite and bundle creation

Tags: templates, netsuite

I'm trying to create a netsuite bundle starting from a saved search and its template (an Advanced PDF/HTML Templates).

The problem is that during the creation steps I can see the saved search, but not the template.

Can anyone explain me why? Is there a visibility attribute to set in the template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Advanced PDF Template is not yet supported in SuiteBundle.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I noticed that when I create a new advanced template by customizing a standard one, I can see the new template in the bundle creation process.

If I start from a "saved search", I don't...

It is weird, ins't it?